# Is it possible to map a url to directory with Grails instead of Apache?

Tags: apache, grails

I started experimenting with Grails. 
So far, I have been able to implement a small web site and generate the controller and views to run the different CRUD operations for my bean.

I wanted to know if it was possible to map a url to a filesystem with Grails? 
I know how to do this with Apache. For instance you can securely serve files from /var/www mapped to a url.

But I was curious to see if it was possible with Grails? Is there a plugin?

Thanks for the help,

Comment: First, you should limit your question to a single question per post. Second, what do you mean by "map a url to a directory"? Are you trying to serve static assets (html, etc?) from that directory?

Comment: Hi, I removed the second question and updated the post.

Comment: It's still unclear what you mean when you say "serve files". If you are looking to include resources such as css, jpg, js, etc. files from an external directory to be used in your GSP files then the asset pipeline or resources plugin will do that just fine, if you want to serve full URLs and HTML files from there then that's something you need to handle outside of Grails and through your container (e.g. Tomcat).

Comment: I meant something like using the Webdav plugin: https://grails.org/wiki/Webdav%20Plugin for a site. I found the svn repository: http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-webdav/trunk/sampleapps/webdav-testapp/ and the sample app to download: http://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/~tarball=zip/grails-plugins/grails-webdav/trunk/sampleapps/webdav-testapp/webdav-testapp.zip